# Dynamically changing href property not working on <a> tag

Tags: jquery, bind

I changed `<a href="">` property on the fly on click on radio button. Now, when I click the a tag.. it is not working as expected.

```
$('.poll input:radio').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {   
       $("#bts_EmailOverlayLink").attr('href','http://qa.makinglifebetterv1.com/offers/doitallmomscontest/default.aspx');
   });      
});
```

Please help me out.

Comment: How is it not working as expected. Did it blow up your pc? Did it make your cat bold? Did it create world peace (if it did I would keep it that way)?

Comment: Unless you have more then one instance of that anchor, and you happen to be testing any of them other then the first one, please disregard my proposed solution below. The code you listed here, although not optimal, should theoretically work. I'd say you may have something going on with your markup instead. Double-check your selectors. Here's a working version based on your snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/jgarrido/uHVxE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing, but hopefully this is what you meant to do.  There is no reason to loop through the radio buttons, just do this (I tested it and it works for me):

```
$('.poll input:radio').click(function() {
   $('#bts_EmailOverlayLink').attr('href', 'http://qa.makinglifebetterv1.com/offers/doitallmomscontest/default.aspx');
});
```

**EDIT**

For those of you that arrive to this page and are using jQuery 1.7+, jQuery's new (and recommended) way of binding events to elements is to use the the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.  Although the above will still work, internally it will be rewritten to use `.on` anyway.

```
$('.poll input:radio').on('click', function() {
   $('#bts_EmailOverlayLink').attr('href', 'http://qa.makinglifebetterv1.com/offers/doitallmomscontest/default.aspx');
});
```